# Noise box, when a table layout is scrolling, without 'AutoScroll' property enabled

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, tablelayout, noise

I have a big problem, when I doing a scrolling without 'Autoscrool' property enabled on a table layout, I get a noise box, seems that the layout continue scrolling (see attached image). I have tried update/refresh/invalidate... its container layouts, but I could not get success for my problem.

Other weird behavior that I have is, once have the noise box on the screen, and launched any dialog, the full layout is fixed.

Has anyone had a similar problem before?

see below the code that I'm using to scrool the table layout:

```
    private void panelSelectorTrackBar_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        galleryTableLayoutPanel.Top = panelSelectorTrackBar.Value;
        dashboardPanelDetails.Hide();
    }
```

On where **galleryTableLayoutPanel** is a *TableLayout* instance, *panelSelectorTrackBar* is an *UltraTrackBar* instance.

[image: Noise Box]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the values of the UltraTrackBar set so that they match the possible vertical scroll values of the TableLayoutPanel, it would be better to set the Value of the VerticalScroll rather than moving the location of the control on the form:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Value = ultraTrackBar1.Value;
```